# Machine learning training image resizing

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, computer-vision, training-data

Normally CNN models have the input dimension, which is a fixed size. Lets say 224x224. So at the training phase as well as classification phase we need to resize the images which are in various sizes to match the input size. My question is, to be the model more accurate, do we need to keep the aspect ratio of the images even after resized or we do not need to bother about the aspect ration at training and classification phases?

This is a sample image that i'm prepared before go into input layer;
[image]

I cannot crop a shape like a square since that square may contains other categories as well. Can anyone advice me the best way to prepare the dataset?

following is my resize mechanism;

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def resize(image, width, height):
    dim = None
    (h, w) = image.shape[:2]

    if width is None and height is None:
        return image

    x_off = 0
    y_off = 0

    if h > w:
        r = height / float(h)
        dim = (int(w * r), height)

    else:
        r = width / float(w)
        dim = (width, int(h * r))

    resized = cv2.resize(image, dim, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
    (h_0, w_0) = resized.shape[:2]

    if h_0 > w_0:
        x_off = (224 - w_0)/2
    else:
        y_off = (224 - h_0)/2

    blank_image = np.zeros((height,width,3), np.uint8)

    blank_image[y_off:y_off+h_0,x_off:x_off+w_0] = resized
    return blank_image
```